# cant update numpy in default mac python setup

Tags: python, numpy, permissions, pip, imagej

my setup : MacOS 10.12.3
default mac python version : 2.7.10
default mac python numpy version : 1.8

I wanted to run a program that needs numpy >1.9. I thought it was simple...but turns out to be a pain.
Things i tried already based on older threads i found...without any success :
`pip install numpy`, `pip install --ignore-installed numpy`, `pip install numpy --upgrade`, `pip install --user -U numpy`.

What i didnt manage to run was to uninstal default numpy and then reinstall new one (using `pip uninstall numpy`). There I get (even with sudo):

```
Exception:   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line
70, in run
requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 274, in uninstall
req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 730, in uninstall
paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 126, in remove
renames(path, new_path)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 292, in renames
shutil.move(old, new)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py",
line 302, in move
copy2(src, real_dst)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py",
line 131, in copy2
copystat(src, dst)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py",
line 103, in copystat
os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)   **OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
'/tmp/pip-g1dBU9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'**
```

I did manage to get homebrew python3 and get the program running in terminal, but its GUI-version is implemented in an another program (imageJ) that calls the default python2.7 and naturally fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `pip3` instead of `pip`

Comment: `pip3 install numpy` gives : "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.17.4)".  
but then `python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.version.version)"`
gives again numpy 1.8. 
I guess the pip3 finds the python3, which is indeed 1.17?

MacOS python resides in : /usr/bin/python
while homebrew python3 is in : /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: Hm, it's something specific to Python 2.7 then. Not sure why you would not be allowed to write to this temp directory with sudo

Comment: I think your last command yielded an error because you were trying to uninstall NumPy for the default Python distribution on your computer. So I guess you can try updating NumPy on your default distribution, or get imageJ to call your homebrew distribution...

Comment: @Tibbles that is true.But as you see from my initial post, i already tried to update the numpy on my default distribution, but with no success... In specific it gives _Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python_, but still i get the 1.8....
On the later suggestion, indeed i could get imageJ call the homebrew distribution...if only i knew how.... :/

Comment: ```pip3 install numpy``` does only tell you that your homebrew Python 3 distribution has the latest available NumPy version (1.17.4). Can you first check which NumPy version you have in your system/default Python 2.7 distribution with ```/usr/bin/python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"``` ?

Comment: Then I guess you could try installing the newer version using ```sudo easy_install numpy``` ?

Comment: @Tibbles for /usr/bin/python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)" give the old 1.8 numpy version.
easy_install gives --> Searching for numpy
Best match: numpy 1.8.0rc1
numpy 1.8.0rc1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

its so confusing...the easy-install i think is somehow not supported anymore, maybe thats why it only finds old version of numpy

Comment: Ok! Well... Can I ask what OS version are you using on your Mac? Might not be the answer you're looking for but I guess it might be worth updating it... I'm currently using macOS Catalina, have never modified my system Python distribution, and I have NumPy 1.13.3.

Comment: Please see original post.